# Как исправить эту ошибку CppHello.cpp(24): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'char *[10]' to 'char *'

Tags: c++, python-3.x

Учусь писать расширения для Python 3 на C++

**HHello.h**

```
// заголовочный файл класса HHello.h
// интерфейс класса

namespace hello {
    // объявление класса
    class CppHello // имя класса
    {
        public: // спецификатор доступа public
        // пример объявления строки
        char* name[10]; // имя
        CppHello(); // конструктор класса
        ~CppHello();//
        char* setName(char* name);
        char* message(); // функция (метод класса) выводящая сообщение на экран
    }; // конец объявления класса Hello
}
```

**CppHello.cpp**

```
// файл реализации класса CppHello.cpp
// подключаем интерфейс класса к файлу его реализации

#include "HHello.h"

using namespace hello;

CppHello::CppHello() // конструктор класса
{
}

CppHello::~CppHello() // деструктор класса
{

}

char* CppHello::setName(char* name) {
    name = name;
    return "Ok.";
}

char* CppHello::message() {

    return "Hello", name;
}
```

**hello.pyx**

```
cdef extern from "HHello.h" namespace "hello":
cdef cppclass CppHello:
    CppHello() except +
    char* name
    char* setName(char*)
    char* message()

cdef class PyHello:
    cdef CppHello *cpp_hello
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.cpp_hello = new CppHello()
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.cpp_hello

    def setName(self, name):
        return self.cpp_hello.setName(name)
    def message(self):
        return self.cpp_hello.message()
```

**Вывод командной строки**

```
CppHello.cpp
CppHello.cpp(24): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'char *[10]' to 
'char *'
CppHello.cpp(24): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires 
reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

**P.S.** Ну и хотелось бы услышать советы и замечания

*Что должно получиться?*

```
from hello import PyHello

def main():
    hello = PyHello()
    print(hello.setName(b"Александр"))
    print(hello.message()) # --> Привет Александр

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Что значит `char* name[10]; // имя`? Почему некое "имя" вдруг представлено массивом из 10 указателей??? Также: `return "Ok.";` не пройдет. Строковый литерал нельзя вернуть как `char *`.

Comment: Я в Cpp почти 0) потому и спрашиваю как будет правильно этот код результат того что я понимаю

Comment: @Александр для начала надо хотя бы на базовом уровне освоить C++, а уж потом браться за нетривиальные задачи вроде написания расширений для Python.

Comment: @Александр: "Как правильно" зависит от того "что надо получить". Я не знаю, что именно вам надо получить. То, что вы "в Cpp почти 0" не означает, что вы пишете код путем случайного долбления молотком по клавиатуре. Вы написали `char* name[10];` по какой-то причине. В чем эта причина? Почему `[10]`?

Comment: Создал объект строка что - бы потом его использовать)

Comment: @Александр: С-строка - это массив символов `char [N]`. У вас же там болтается `*`. Откуда взялась эта `*`? Зачем вы ее туда вписали?

Comment: AnT если бы я только знал)

Comment: А что значит эта звёздочка? после char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, исходя из (абсолютно неверного!)

```
char* CppHello::setName(char* name) {
    name = name;
    return "Ok.";
}
```

вы хотели использовать указатель

```
char* name;
```

Если же вы хотели хранить строку во внутреннем массиве - то нужно

```
char name[10];
```

и

```
strcpy(name...
```

Теперь вернемся к конкретной ошибке

```
return "Hello", name;
```

Это не Питон, вы тут возвращаете *только* `name` (см. "оператор запятая").

А вот тут

```
char* CppHello::setName(char* name) {
    name = name;
    return "Ok.";
}
```

вы присваиваете переданному аргументу его же :) - чтобы работать в такой ситуации с членом класса `name`, нужно использовать `this->name`.

Ну, а присваивать или копировать - зависит от решения, где хранится строка.

Comment: И как в C++ правильно вернуть 2 строки?

Comment: Вы уверены в формулировке? Именно **две строки**, а не результат их конкатенации? И - именно **строки**, или **массива символов** (мы же в C++, правда)?

Comment: Да результат их конкатенации

Comment: Опять же - если строки, то что-то типа `string s("Hello "); s += name; return s;`. Если массива - то где-то нужно выделить место (только если вы выделите локально массив, то, возвращая указатель на него, получите неприятности... где именно вы выделите память - это зависит от самого дизайна вашей системы и других решений). Потом - `strcpy(s,"Hello "); strcat(s, name); return name;` - только нужно точно убедиться, что места в массиве хватает. И еще раз - не забудьте решить, кто им владеет!

Comment: По ошибке то что мне делать я так понимаю функция объявлена как char а возвращает массив поэтому происходит ошибка или не так?

Comment: Мой вам совет - не пытайтесь заткнуть конкретную дыру. Этим вы сделаете штук 5 новых. Почитайте про строки, как с ними работать, передавать в функции и назад...

Comment: const char *greeting = "Привет"; как greeting закодировать в utf-8?